# What is the meaning of %©»ªµ in a PDF code header?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a PDF in my Android application using the [Android PDF Writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/). This is a very basic library that allows to create simple PDF files. It works quite well, but there is one thing I do not understand:

When I look at the generated PDF source code I can see, that the file starts with the following lines:

```
%PDF-1.4
%©»ªµ
1 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
...
```

**What does the second line mean?** I searched a lot of different PDF syntax documentations but I have found no hint what that line could mean. In all examples I found the the `%PDF-VersionXY` line is directly followed by the first object / the catalog.

I am not sure if this is valid PDF code at all, or if this some an error due to some charset/enconding problem with the libraries source code.

**Any idea what this could be about?** What information could be included at this place and is `%©»ªµ` valid PDF or some enconding error?**

Comment: Well, since it begins with a `%` it's a comment, and, from what I can find, it seems like it's included to ensure that programs don't try to open the file as plain text. Also, it seems that that particular string isn't necessarily standard; it need only comprise non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When taking a look at the pdf-1.4 reference [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html) (or also in the current 1.7 [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) in section 3.4.1 it says

> Note: If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do (see Section 3.1, “Lexical Conventions”),
>   it is recommended that the header line be immediately followed by a
>   comment line containing at least four binary characters—that is, characters whose
>   codes are 128 or greater. This will ensure proper behavior of file transfer applications
>   that inspect data near the beginning of a file to determine whether to treat the file’s
>   contents as text or as binary.

So your generator seems to include this additional comment-line by default, even if there is no binary data to follow. What's in there doesn't matter as long as each byte value is > 128 (that is: outside the ASCII-range). In your case it's hex values `A9 BB AA B5`, so everything is fine and you don't have to worry about this line.